# GetLastInputTime shows impossible time?

Tags: c#, winapi

To determine, if PC was not used for certain amount of time, I'm using  `Win32API.GetLastInputTime()` method. I'm just subtracting its value from DateTime.Now, and compare it with some value, stored in settings.

It worked perfectly before, but recently `GetLastInputTime` started to show completely ridiculous results - it shows me future time. Today it shows me July 2nd of 2016.

So, does anyone has any idea, what's happening? How does `GetLastInputTime` get time, and how it is possible, that this time is future one?

Comment: Probably -- or rather maybe -- there is something wrong with the processing of the `DateTime` class. Note that 02/07/2016 can be either read as July 2nd 2016 or Feb 7th 2016. But without more info, it is hard to tell if this be the problem.

Comment: Another possibility is that `GetLastInputTime` returns *ticks* which are prone to exhaust: "...the time will wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for 49.7 days..." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx; please, notice that `13 May 2016 +49.7 day` == `2 July 2016`

Comment: Subtracting it from DateTime.Now is meaningless, that produces the date the machine was rebooted.  You have to cast it to *int* and subtract it from Environment.TickCount.  Which produces the number of milliseconds since the last input event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `GetLastInputTime` returns *ticks* as `UInt32` (`DWORD`)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx

you can have an integer *overflow*:

> The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD value. Therefore, the time will
>   wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for **49.7 days**.
>   To avoid this problem, use the GetTickCount64 function. Otherwise,
>   check for an overflow condition when comparing times.

And thus have *future* dates:

```
   13 May 2016 + 49.7 days == 2 July 2016
```

Comment: Ok, I've adapted my code to use GetLastInputInfo and Environment.TickCount. Thanks for outlining core of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not use DateTime.Now because it depends on the time zone.

As described [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getlastinputinfo), you have to use `Environment.TickCount` to get the idle time.

Comment: It is true that the `DateTime.Now` depends on the time zone - just as you say. But the result the OP gets is too far off even for different time zone. Likely the problem is not with the use of `DateTime.Now` - but the entire processing of `DateTime`. Anyway, without further info, it is hard to tell.